# Hyper-V: Check if host is part of any cluster

Tags: powershell, virtualization, hyper-v, powershell-remoting

I want to check if particular Hyper-V node is part of any cluster or not.

I just have name of Hyper-V machine, say `HyperV01` and I want to check if this machine is part of any cluster.

Also I will be executing this script on any machine on the network.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This will return true if the host is part of any cluster and false if it's not (https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/da51bcca-8407-45c3-896a-0df98014a4d5):

```
if((Get-WMIObject -Class MSCluster_ResourceGroup -ComputerName $Servername -Namespace root\mscluster) -ne $null){return $true}else {return $false}
```

Comment: Another way of doing it (requiers FailoverClusters psmodule) is: Get-Cluster -Domain domain.com | Get-ClusterNode | where {$_.Name -eq $servername} | select name,cluster

Comment: How install ***FailoverClusters psmodule*** ?

Comment: How Get ***if host is active node in Cluster*** ?

Comment: Hi @Kiquenet, to install FailoverClusters psmodule, run this command (in elevated PS):
"Install-WindowsFeature RSAT-Clustering-PowerShell"

Comment: @Kiquenet, don't know what you mean with acitve node but if you only mean the status you can get it with:
"Get-Cluster -Name <clustername> | Get-ClusterNode"
And then check the status.